# What does POCO mean?

Tags: .net, poco

I have seen many articles about POCO. What is this?

Comment: It all depends on what else these articles are about - see the answers for possible candidates, or post exactly which "side of the fence" you're on.

Comment: Agreed. Please specify context and retag it as such.

Comment: Could you at least post the language? I see at one .NET meaning and two C++ meanings for this acronym.

Comment: Please retag and tell us the language

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[Plain old CLR object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object)

Comment: Its the C# equivalent of a POJO http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POJO

Comment: It's C++ in every thing that I've read outside of that Wikipedia article. Could you link to a use of this outside of Wikipedia?

Comment: https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/quickstart.html

Comment: As Gishu states - POCO is derived from POJO.

Comment: Not derived from, just the equivalent of.

Comment: @Will - It is the equivalent of but it was derived from POJO as POJO was first.

Comment: How can the description of an acronym have an acronym inside it!!! Come on!

Comment: To try give an example, rather than just a definition: the classes you build in your BL are often POCOs. So if you create a simple Customer class, with attributes of int CustomerID, string Name, DateTime DateOfBirth - that's a POCO; it's only used by you. The List<T> class is not a POCO - it inherits IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, (etc) and it's often user by other parts of the .NET Framework - i.e. it's part of the .NET Framework fabric, and is not a POCO.

Answer (score 35):

Based in the language you want to choose **POCO** means

> Plain Old **CLR** Object

as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POCO) mention or,

> Plain Old **C++** Object

as the [PocoCapsule](http://code.google.com/p/pococapsule/) mentions it or,

> POrtable COmponents

as the [POCO Project](http://pocoproject.org/) mentions it.

For what I'm concerned and for the reason of this question, and of course in simple words, it's a [C++ library](http://pocoproject.org/). :)

> The [POCO C++ Libraries](http://pocoproject.org/) aim to be for network-centric, cross-platform C++ software development what Apple's Cocoa is for Mac development, or Ruby on Rails is for Web development — a powerful, yet easy to use platform to build your applications upon.
>
> The [POCO C++ Libraries](http://pocoproject.org/) are built strictly on standard ANSI/ISO C++, including the standard library. The developers of the POCO C++ Libraries attempt to find a good balance between using advanced C++ features and keeping the classes comprehensible and the code clean, consistent and easy to maintain.

Comment: This is probably the lesser known acronym in .NET circles :-) Don't know why you got a downvote for that, though - compensated.

Comment: :) no need to compensate, but thank you anyway. They downvoted for a reason... I would love this to happend: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/41056-force-user-to-comment-on-downvote

Comment: Isn't normal C++ term "Plain Old Data"?

Answer (score 10):

The POCO C++ Libraries (POCO stands for POrtable COmponents) are **open source C++ class libraries** that simplify and **accelerate the development** of network-centric, portable applications in C++. The libraries integrate perfectly with the C++ Standard Library and fill many of the functional gaps left open by it. Their **modular and efficient** design and implementation makes the POCO C++ Libraries extremely well suited for embedded development, an area where the C++ programming language is becoming increasingly popular, due to its suitability for both low-level (device I/O, interrupt handlers, etc.) and high-level object-oriented development. Of course, the POCO C++ Libraries are also ready for enterprise-level challenges.

The POCO C++ Libraries **free developers from re-inventing the wheel**, and allow them to spend their time on more worthwhile areas, such as getting things done quickly and working on the features that make their application unique.

[Source and More Information](http://pocoproject.org/)

Answer (score 6):

If you are talking .NET:

> POCO = Plain Old Class (or CLR) Object

Please See: [POCO vs DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725348/poco-vs-dto)

Answer (score 4):

Acronyms like this usually stand for "Plain Old..." such as POX meaning Plain Old XML.

I would therefore guess that POCO was either Plain Old C Object, or Plain Old Class Object or some derivative. It would help if I knew the context (such as the programming language you are using).

Answer (score 2):

lainMH and Darnell have already given you the answer. As is says in the Wikipedia article is a reference to the term [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object), and the background of that term is found at [Martin Fowlers' website](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/POJO.html).

Answer (score 1):

POCO stands for [Plain Old C++ Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_C++_Object).