# How to access Session values from layers beneath the web application layer

Tags: asp.net, session, separation-of-concerns

We have many instances in our application where we would like to be able to access things like the currently logged in user id in our business domain and data access layer.  On log we push this information to the session, so all of our front end code has access to it fairly easily of course.  However, we are having huge issues getting at the data in lower layers of our application.  We just can't seem to find a way to store a value in the business domain that has global scope just for the user (static classes and properties are of course shared by the application domain, which means all users in the session share just one copy of the object).  We have considered passing in the session to our business classes, but then our domain is very tightly coupled to our web application.  We want to keep the prospect of a winforms version of the application possible going forward.

I find it hard to believe we are the first people to have this sort of issue.  How are you handling this problem in your applications?

Comment: What a difference 8 years makes. These days, it's trivially easy to wrap up any session requirements in an interface, and use your DI container to inject it where appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think having your business classes rely on a global object is that great of an idea, and would avoid it if possible. You *should* be injecting the necessary information into them - this makes them much more testable and scalable.

So rather than passing a `Session` object directly to them, you should wrap up the information access methods that you need into a repository class.  Your business layer can use the repository class as a data source (call `GetUser()` on it, for example), and the repository for your web app can use session to retrieve the requested information (return `_session.User.Identity`).

When porting it to winforms, simply implement the repository interface with a new winform-centric class (i.e. `GetUser()` returns the windows version of the user principal).

Answer (score 1):

In theory people will tell you it's a bad business practice. 
In practice, we just needed the data from the session level available in the business layers all the time. :-(

We ended up having different storage engines united under a small interface.

```
public interface ISessionStorage 
{
   SomeSessionData Data {get;set;}
   ...
   .. and most of the data we need stored at "session" level
    }
 //and a singleton to access it
    public static ISessionStorage ISessionStorage;
```

this interface is available from almost anywhere in our code.

Then we have both a Session and/or a singleton implementation

```
 public WebSessionStorage
{
   public SomeSessionData Data 
  {
       get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["somekey"] as SomeSessionData;}
      set { HttpContext.Current.Session["somekey"] = value;}
  }

public WebFormsSessionStorage
{
   private static SomeSessionData  _SomeSessionData; //this was before automatic get;set;
   public SomeSessionData 
   {
       get{ return _SomeSessionData;}
       set{ _SomeSessionData=value; }
}
```

}

On initing the application, the website will do a

```
 Framework.Storage.SessionStorage = new WebSessionStorage();
```

in Global.asax, and the FormsApp will do

```
 Framework.Storage.SessionStorage = new WebFormsSessionStorage();
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Womp completely - inject the data down from your front-end into your lower tiers.

If you want to do a half-way cheat (but not too much of a cheat), what you can do is create a very small assembly with just a couple [POCO classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910253/what-is-poco) to store all of this information you want to share across all of your tiers (currently logged-in username, time logged in, etc.) and just pass this object from your front-end into your biz/data tiers. Now if you do this, you MUST avoid the temptation to turn this POCO assembly into a general utility assembly - it MUST stay small or you WILL have problems in the future (trust me or learn the hard way or ask somebody else to elaborate on this one). However, if you have this POCO assembly, injecting this data through the various tiers becomes very easy and since it's POCO, it serializes very well and works nicely with web services, WCF, etc.