# Some quick knowledge about POCO

Tags: entity-framework, poco

I'm recently looking at entity framework4, it mentioned POCO. What is that? And what is that used for? Who can give some quick understanding to me? Or some suggested URLs? Thanks. By the way, does it commonly/often used by real life projects?

Answer (score 1):

"Plain old CLR Object".  It refers to objects that don't have anything "special" going on such as extending base classes defined in some special EF4 entity assembly.  Or, at least, if they do extend base classes, it doesn't require special "tools" installed in Visual Studio that generates code.  Examples of this include the strongly-typed DataSet and Linq to Sql designer (code named SQLMetal).

Answer (score 0):

Its just a plain old clr object.  Check these URLs out for more information.

[What does POCO mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910253/what-is-poco)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object

Hope this helps