# Can someone explain why use ViewModels in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, architecture, viewmodel

In researching MVC 3 archetectures, one thing I've seen consistently is the concept of breaking the models out into their own project and calling it ViewModels.

As I'm coding, I'm having a hard time realizing what the benefit of this is.  Could someone explain what the advantages of this are?

Comment: Are you asking why use ViewModels at all, or why put ViewModels into its own project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure where you go thid idea that View models should be in their own project.  That's typically not how it's done.

Often the business model is in a seperate project, as is the data model, but the view models are typically in the web project where they belong, since they're a part of the presentation layer.

Comment: The only answer that answers the question.

Comment: Well, except for mine. But this one is more direct.

Comment: I'm not sure where I got that idea either, hence why it didn't make sense to me.  Thanks for the answers all!

Answer (score 2):

Because one major thing about MVC is **seperation of concern**. You should create a ViewModel that has only the data your View needs, no logic.

**You can, but you don't need, a seperate project (for example: a Data Access Layer)**

A ViewModel is just a simple POCO class (Plain Old CLR Object, a class that only has properties, no logic)

#### More Information

- [Wikipedia - Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)
- [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)
- [ASP.NET MVC View Model Patterns](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx)
- [ASP.NET MVC Tip #50 – Create View Models](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx)
- [What is POCO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910253/what-is-poco)
- [Use ViewModels to manage data & organize code in ASP.NET MVC applications](http://www.rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp.net-mvc-applications)

Comment: Right, but why put this in a whole seperate project instead of leaving it in the MVC app?

Comment: No, you dont need a seperate project. You should load you data and asign it to a simple class with the data your view needs.

Comment: This looks like a good start: http://www.rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp.net-mvc-applications. Perhaps right for some situations, not for all, though. Actually, that's good enough to be an answer.

Comment: @MrBoJangles Thanks, my answer is extended

Answer (score 1):

ViewModels are used to tailor a Model for the use of a particular View.  When you want to pass specific information to the View, or retrieve particular information, then you would construct a ViewModel.

An example of a ViewModel would be:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public Person NewPerson { get ; set ; }
    public Address NewAddress { get ; set ; }
    public SelectList Suffixes { get ; set ; }
}
```

If you had a view that created a new person, you could pass it this ViewModel class that is designed soley for the purpose of a new person View.

Comment: Right, but why put this in a whole seperate project instead of leaving it in the MVC app?

Comment: @Scottie you could separate your ViewModels if you like.  That is personal preference and structure of the application.  Like your Controllers, Models, and Views, ViewModels can exist inside of the MVC project.

Answer (score 1):

View models are a part of the UI layer so they should generally stay in the same project.