# Data provider class for sql database

Tags: sql, azure, orm, data-access-layer

I need to write a data provider class to pull data from a sql database for use in a webpage that will display a bing map.  Does anyone have a link they could provide with a tutorial on how to do this?

I have very little experience using a db to provide dynamic data for a web page so any help is appreciated.  The Database is a sql Azure databse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to research Data Access in .NET and ORM technologies for .NET.  This question deals with similar concepts.

[Simple Data Access Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681274/simple-data-access-layer)

Note: There is nothing "special" you need to do to apply the standard .NET data technologies to Azure SQL.