# EF POCO DTO WCF Adapter pattern

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework-4, adapter, poco

So I'm starting to look into using the EF with POCO and transfering DTO over the wire to client of my WCF.

Looks like it's a good architectural design to go with DTO instead of sending POCO over to the client.

So I was reading about it and a lot of time it mentionned using the Adapter pattern to convert the POCO to DTO.

I can't seem to find any article describing the Adapter patter used for POCO => DTO.

Can someone shed a bit of light concerning this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) is GoW pattern with exact meaning. You don't need special article to read about using it on top of POCO and DTOs (it is same like with any other classes). But I think you actually don't want a real adapter. You want something which will convert POCO to DTO and vice versa. Many developers are using very good library called [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/). I usually don't use neither adapter or AutoMapper. Instead my DTO's have static methods called `ToPoco` and `FromPoco` - it is stupid, it is more writting but everybody understand it.

Comment: I was wondering how to use it with the adapter pattern. Going with this http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAdapter.aspx i was thinking so the target is the DTO ... so i create an adapter to wrap my poco? ...

Answer (score 1):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725348/poco-vs-dto) talks about the purity of the two.

But as far as converting them from one to the other, I have used extension methods in the past.

So before the POCO is being sent over the wire, I have something like this.

```
accountPoco.toDTO()
```

which converts it into a WCF datacontract obj, serialized and sent across the wire.

On the other side I have

```
accountDto.toPOCO()
```

Which converts it back into POCO.

It's not the most elegant, but it works.