# 'RestClient' does not contain a definition for 'Execute'

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp

I have been working on getting an api authentication to work and I am currently stuck on getting the response to execute to show up in a text box.

```
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user = textBoxUsername.Text;
        string password = textBoxPassword.Text;
        string tenant = comboBoxCompany.Text;
        var client = new RestClient("https://server_name/v2/security/authenticate");
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Method = Method.Post;

        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");

        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "grantType=password&userName={{username}}&password={{password}}&tenant={{company_name}}", ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request); <= //error here // red line is under the 'Execute'

        textBoxJson.Text = response.ToString();


    }
}
public class IRestResponse
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public List<AuthenticationResponseData> result { get; set; }
}
public class AuthenticationResponseData
{
    public string accesstoken { get; set; }
    public string refreshtoken { get; set; }
    public string accessTokenExpiresOn { get; set; }
    public string refreshTokenExpiresOn { get; set; }        
    }
```

This is within a form page.

Comment: What is `RestClient`?  Are you using [RestSharp](https://restsharp.dev/)?  The error is pretty clear that `RestClient` doesn't have an `Execute` method.  What led you to believe that it does?

Comment: Hello thanks for the response. I am new to using working with api authentication. I am using RestSharp. What would be the easiest way to write out method to execute the authentication within a class called RestClient?

Comment: I believe that both .Execute and the rest of the non-async methods have been deprecated in newer versions of RestSharp. There is a .ExecuteAsync method, however, `IRestResponse` is not available through RestSharp. Are you *sure* you're using RestSharp?

Comment: I suggest reading the [documentation](https://restsharp.dev/intro.html#basic-usage). I've never used RestSharp, but the example there shows `client.GetAsync()` being used...

Answer (score 0):

<strike>var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("RESOURCE", RestSharp.Method.POST) { RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json }
.AddBody(BODY);</strike>

```
var response = Client.Execute(request);

// Handle response errors
HandleResponseErrors(response);
```

from [How to POST request using RestSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400879/how-to-post-request-using-restsharp)

Comment: And this is currently no longer working since .Execute has been deprecated. 10 year old answers should be validated to ensure they're still valid.