# What is a CLR class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I googled CLR and found out what it is from wikipedia, but I wanted to know what a CLR class or more specifically a CLR entity type is (especially in ASP.NET).

Comment: Have you read this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382837.aspx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are probably talking about CLR objects / POCO objects - Plain Old CLR objects.

Look here: [POCO vs DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725348/poco-vs-dto)

Look here about working with POCO entities - [Working with POCO Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx)

Comment: I was specifically referring to CLR being mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295845%28v=vs.103%29.aspx - for example - "Mapping a CLR entity type to a specific table in the database".

Answer (score 43):

**CLR is not class**. The Common Language Runtime (CLR) is the virtual machine component of Microsoft's .NET framework . This runtime environment in .NET Framework is known as Common Language Runtime (CLR).

image from wiki which explain what clr can do

[image]

CLR provides the following benefits for developers:

- Vastly simplified development.
- Seamless integration of code written
  in various languages.
- Evidence-based security with code identity.
- Assembly-based deployment that eliminates DLL Hell.
- Side-by-side
  versioning of reusable components.
- Code reuse through implementation
  inheritance.
- Automatic object lifetime management.
- Code access
  security.
- Cross Language Integration.
- Self describing objects.

Read more : https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?369619

Comment: The question states "What is a clr class". As you can create "A project for creating CLR classes to use in other applications" in Visual C++ (at least in Visual Studio 2012), your bold (as in font weight bold) statement implies the question is wrong / not valid. While it is actually acurate and valid.

Comment: But question tags don't include C++, maybe that's the reason why Pranay wrote it like that.

Answer (score 3):

CLR is Common Language Runtime not a class.

The Common Language Runtime (CLR) is the virtual machine component of Microsoft's .NET framework and is responsible for managing the execution of .NET programs. In a process known as just-in-time (JIT) compilation, the CLR compiles the intermediate language code known as CIL into the machine instructions that in turn are executed by the computer's CPU. The CLR provides additional services including memory management, type safety and exception handling. All programs written for the .NET framework, regardless of programming language, are executed by the CLR. It provides exception handling, Garbage collection and thread management.

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bs2ecf4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

CLR refers to Common Language Runtime, while class refers to a strongly typed data instance. The CLR is responsible for amongst many other things, managing the memory of your class instances.