# How to use json.net(JObject/Jarray/Jtoken) and convert to class in the fastest way into a dictionary?

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, json.net

How to use json.net(JObject/Jarray/Jtoken) and convert to class in the fastest(performance) way into a dictionary? the key of the dictionary is the sees "name" in the json file

Can anyone help?

Thanks alot!

```
seed.json
       {
          "Seed": [
                {
                    "name": "Cheetone",
                    "growthrate": 1,
                    "cost": 500
                },
                {
                    "name": "Tortone",
                    "growthrate": 8,
                    "cost": 100
                }
            ],
        }


    public class SoilStat
    {
        public int growthRate;
        public int cost;
    }

    public class DataLoader : MonoSingleton<DataLoader>
    {
        public string txt;
        Dictionary<string, SoilStat> _soilList = new Dictionary<string, SoilStat>();

        JObject rawJson = JObject.Parse(txt);

        ???
    }
```

Comment: What is `_txtAsset`?  Is it that snippet of JSON at the top?  If so, can you please provide the actual valid JSON you are using?  (as it is, it's malformed)

Comment: Your question sounds very general but the actual code you show seems not to be so.  What are the dictionary keys supposed to be?

Comment: updated the code @dbc

Comment: By "fastest" do you mean "most performant" or "most straightforward"?

Comment: Then I may point you to [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert).  I can give you a very simple way to do what you want but you'll need to do performance testing yourself.  Want it?

Comment: Yes want it! thanks! @dbc

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do what you want is to use [`SelectTokens`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenWithLinq.htm) to pick out the portions of JSON of interest to you, then just deserialize those bits.  Thus:

```
        var rawJson = JObject.Parse(txt);
        var _soilList = rawJson.SelectTokens("Seed[*]").ToDictionary(t => t["name"], t => t.ToObject<SoilStat>());
```

A more complex solution would be to create [DTO objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725348/poco-vs-dto) for deserialization then map them to your desired classes:

```
public class NamedSoilStat : SoilStat
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public RootObject() { this.Seed = new List<NamedSoilStat>(); }
    public List<NamedSoilStat> Seed { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(txt);
        var _soilList = root.Seed.ToDictionary(t => t.name, t => new SoilStat { cost = t.cost, growthRate = t.growthRate });
```

As to which is more performant, you would need to [test for yourself](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Incidentally, if your `txt` JSON string is coming from a file, and is large, you should consider streaming it in rather than reading it into an intermediate string.  See [Performance Tips: Optimize Memory Usage](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm).

Comment: I cant use selecttoken due to some restriction on unity5. is there other way to do it without creating DTO object? @dbc

Answer (score 1):

In my experiences, using `JsonConvert` is significantly faster than using `JObject.Parse()`.  See [this page for a performance comparison](http://gregstoll.livejournal.com/442935.html) (on Windows Phone, but I'd imagine it would be similar on desktop), and linked from that page is [an example that uses JsonConvert](https://gist.github.com/martinsuchan/8372808).

Comment: thanks but how do i use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject into dictionary with seed "name" as the key?