# Can't deserialize an object using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

Tags: c#, json.net

I receive a string in this format:

```
   {
  "ok": true,
  "quote": { // the below is the same as returned through the REST quote API
    "symbol": "FAC",
    "venue": "OGEX",
    "bid": 5100, // best price currently bid for the stock
    "ask": 5125, // best price currently offered for the stock
    "bidSize": 392, // aggregate size of all orders at the best bid
    "askSize": 711, // aggregate size of all orders at the best ask
    "bidDepth": 2748, // aggregate size of *all bids*
    "askDepth": 2237, // aggregate size of *all asks*
    "last": 5125, // price of last trade
    "lastSize": 52, // quantity of last trade
    "lastTrade": "2015-07-13T05:38:17.33640392Z", // timestamp of last trade,
    "quoteTime": "2015-07-13T05:38:17.33640392Z" // server ts of quote generation
  }
}
```

I want to use the Newtonsoft.Json.Linq way of deserializing for performance reasons. When I try to turn the Json string into a Quote object using the following method:

```
 public static Quote QuoteFromJson(string quoteJson)
        {
            var json = JObject.Parse(quoteJson);
            var quote = json["quote"].
                Select(q => new Quote
                {
                    Ask = int.Parse(q["ask"].ToString()),
                    AskDepth = int.Parse(q["askDepth"].ToString()),
                    AskSize = int.Parse(q["askSize"].ToString()),
                    Bid = int.Parse(q["bid"].ToString()),
                    BidDepth = int.Parse(q["bidDepth"].ToString()),
                    BidSize = int.Parse(q["bidSize"].ToString()),
                    Last = int.Parse(q["last"].ToString()),
                    LastSize = int.Parse(q["lastSize"].ToString()),
                    LastTrade = q["lastTrade"].ToString(),
                    QuoteTime = q["quoteTime"].ToString(),
                    Symbol = q["symbol"].ToString(),
                }).First();

            return quote;
        }
```

This gives an error message:

```
Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you directly parse it to a `Quote`? Like this: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(quoteJson)`

Comment: That would make life easy, but DeserializeObject uses Reflection, which slows down my app considerably.

Comment: Slower than dipping to a JObject property by property to construct your object?

Comment: If Json.NET isn't fast enough for you, I suggest you look into other libraries before resorting to your current method. This is very messy. I would also suggest you set performance goals based on business needs, not just by looking at a profiler going, "OH MAN I SPENT SO MUCH TIME DESERIALIZING". Chances are you are spending WAY more time actually doing network IO than you are deserializing.

Comment: Linq to JSON might not be faster than deserialization.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279454/how-to-use-json-netjobject-jarray-jtoken-and-convert-to-class-in-the-fastest-w/34279736#34279736) for a comparison of deserialization vs direct parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a direct answer to your question:

The `quote` variable corresponds to the `quote` token in your JSON. This is a single item and not a collection, so you shouldn't treat it as a collection and use the `Select` method.

Instead, access it directly like this:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(quoteJson);

var quote = json["quote"];

var result = new Quote
{
    Ask = int.Parse(quote["ask"].ToString()),
    AskDepth = int.Parse(quote["askDepth"].ToString()),
    AskSize = int.Parse(quote["askSize"].ToString()),
    Bid = int.Parse(quote["bid"].ToString()),
    BidDepth = int.Parse(quote["bidDepth"].ToString()),
    BidSize = int.Parse(quote["bidSize"].ToString()),
    Last = int.Parse(quote["last"].ToString()),
    LastSize = int.Parse(quote["lastSize"].ToString()),
    LastTrade = quote["lastTrade"].ToString(),
    QuoteTime = quote["quoteTime"].ToString(),
    Symbol = quote["symbol"].ToString(),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are iterating through the children of `"quote"` with your `Select`, then retrieving their properties by name.  This would be appropriate if `"quote"` were an array, but it's not -- it's already a single object.  Thus you should do:

```
        var rootObj = JObject.Parse(quoteJson);
        var quoteObj = rootObj["quote"];
        var quote = new Quote
        {
            Ask = (int)quoteObj["ask"],
            AskDepth = (int)quoteObj["askDepth"],
            AskSize = (int)quoteObj["askSize"],
            Bid = (int)quoteObj["bid"],
            BidDepth = (int)quoteObj["bidDepth"],
            BidSize = (int)quoteObj["bidSize"],
            Last = (int)quoteObj["last"],
            LastSize = (int)quoteObj["lastSize"],
            LastTrade = (string)quoteObj["lastTrade"],
            QuoteTime = (string)quoteObj["quoteTime"],
            Symbol = (string)quoteObj["symbol"],
        };
```

Note I am using [explicit casting](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Operators_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm).  This handles internationalization of numbers in a manner consistent with the [JSON standard](http://json.org/).  `int.Parse()` parses using localized formatting, which is not guaranteed to be consistent with the standard in all locales.

However, it is much simpler to use deserialization:

```
        var rootObj = JObject.Parse(quoteJson);
        var quoteObj = rootObj["quote"];
        var quote = quoteObj.ToObject<Quote>();
```

I suggest you should time this to make sure it really is slower than Linq to JSON.