# Want the difference between POCO and DTO in C#

Tags: c#

Anybody can explain about the difference between the 
POCO and DTO objects in c# with example
and also go through the below link 
in the below link having four types to transfer data from one layer to another layer
i cant under the link explanations

Four ways of passing data between layers[^]

What I have tried:

please help me out from the confusion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725348/plain-old-clr-object-vs-data-transfer-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plain Old CLR Object vs Data Transfer Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725348/plain-old-clr-object-vs-data-transfer-object)

Comment: @tech5group please google it and StackOverflow community is already given an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

learn to love the POCO, and make sure you don’t spread any misinformation about it being the same thing as a DTO. DTOs are simple data containers used for moving data between the layers of an application. POCOs are full-fledged business objects with the one requirement that they are Persistence Ignorant (no get or save methods)
BTW, Patrick, I read the POCO as a Lifestyle article, and I completely agree, that is a fantastic article.

YOu can check more details form here http://rlacovara.blogspot.com/2009/03/what-is-difference-between-dto-and-poco.html