# transfer objects betwen DAL and BLL

Tags: c#, architecture

We are starting a new web application and we decided to use N-Tier design.

We have some disagreement about the objects that transfer data between layers (DTO),
should there be methods in them?

If it's to organize the data from 2 databases, should we create one DTO for all layer per object? What is the standard?

We are reading the web application design by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DTO object is usaually a container for data and has no behavior. There are many ways of implementing the mapping between tiers using the DTO objects.

You could have some guidelines reading the article about DTO from MS pattern & practice team : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx

There is another ressource on SO : [How to effectively use DTO objects (Data Transfer Objects)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512880/how-to-effectively-use-dto-objects-data-transfer-objects)

You could also have a look on a working project sample "Microsoft - Domain Oriented N-Layered .NET 4.0 App Sample "  : http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/ where many patterns are used and the DTO also.

Comment: We have an object called site that it's data is composed from 2 database (yes i know it terrible - old architecture) while creating a new one by the user we are invoking a method that set the data for an inner object (from the other DB) , i dont like it in the DTO/ POCO i would like it to be in the BLL yet its  the structure of the object  then should it be in the DAL ? is it normal to have that method, can it be a util method in the dao ? what are your thoughts?

Comment: My advice is to keep it simple and stupid (KISS). I like to keep my Separation of concerns. In the simpliest scenarios we have DAL layer and domain layer. The domain references nothing. The DAL knows Domain so it's the only layer when I can implement mapping or helper methods. In your case you can fill the site object with data by a third party framework or custom made helper method but I think it is best to keep that in your dal. "No matter" how it's done as the important thing is where is done.